# How to pass OData query parameters from one action to anoter via in a Redirect

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following scenario: A ProductsController with a "GetAll" method which accepts ODataQueryOptions like so:

```
    [GET("Products", RouteName = "GetAllProducts")]
    public ProductDTO[] Get(ODataQueryOptions options)
    {  
       //parse the options and do whatever...
        return new ProductDTO[] { };
    }
```

and a CategoryController with a GetProducts method like so:

```
    [GET("Category/{id}/Products", RouteName = "GetProductsByCategory")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetProducts(int id, ODataQueryOptions options)
    {
        //Request URL can be "api/Category/12/Products?$select=Name,Price&$top=10"
        //Need to do a redirect the ProductsController "GetAllProducts" action
        HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod);
        msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("GetAllProducts",options));
        // how do we send the odata query string"$select=Name,Price&$top=10"
        //to the ProductsController? passing "options" directly does not work!
        return msg;
    }
```

I do not want to redefine the logic to fetch products by a specific Category in the CategoryController. 
Is there a way to

1) Pass the ODataQueryOptions as part of the redirect?

2) Can the options be modified to add an additional filter criteria? In the above example, I would like to add an additional filter critera for the current CategoryID before doing the redirect so that the "GetAllProducts" would receive the following request:
  "api/Products?$select=Name,Price&$top=10&**$filter=CategoryID eq 12**"

Does the above make sense or should I be approaching this differently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you need a redirect? Can you just share the lookup logic between both controllers?

Comment: I could but I was hoping to avoid code duplication. If DRY will be a PITA to implement here, I'll fallback on sharing the lookup logic

Answer (score 3):

You can use this helper to get the OData query string from a request.

```
    private static string GetODataQueryString(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return
            String.Join("&", request
                                .GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                                .Where(kvp => kvp.Key.StartsWith("$"))
                                .Select(kvp => String.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Value))));
    }
```

Comment: That's great but how would pass this along in a redirect? Note that I'm using "Url.Link" to get the url based on the route name in the code sample above which in turn is used to set the location in the "msg.Headers.Location".

Comment: Just append this to the uri generated by link method. Make sure you append it as a query string.